# Random number in list C#

Tags: c#, random

Hello I'm having trouble with part of my code. I have a dictionary and the key is a number and the value for the key is a list of random integers between 1-8. For some reason after the first key and value are added all the other key's values are the same as the first. This is the output right now which is wrong.

```
1: 1, 8, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2 ,4
2: 1, 8, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2 ,4
3: 1, 8, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2 ,4
4: 1, 8, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2 ,4
5: 1, 8, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2 ,4
6: 1, 8, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2 ,4
7: 1, 8, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2 ,4
8: 1, 8, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2 ,4
```

I tried to clear the arrayList once the 8 random numbers is added to the list, but then there's no values in the dictionary at all. Does anyone have any suggestions please.

Comment: Take a look at this good article: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: @EmmadKareem: completely irrelevant. His `Random` is declared on instance level which should be enough for a trivial example like this.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, thanks for your hint. I will study your suggestion.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: the issue as described in Jon's article is about creating multiple consecutive instances of `Random`. The `Random` class is pseudorandom: it uses, amongst others, the current time to determine the seed. This means that 2 different instances created at the same time, will probably produce the same seed and thus same random values. You can circumvent this in singlethreaded applications by declaring it once (e.g.: as an instance field). The issue here is described in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private List<int> randomList() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        if (randomNum.Count < 9) {
            randomNum.Add(random.Next(1, 9));
        }
    }
    return randomNum;
}
```

After the first iteration, `randomNum.Count` will never return `false` and thus it will not calculate it again. You can manually reset it like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
     dic.Add(i, randomList());
     randomNum = new List<int>();
}
```

Comment: Wow that one line of code did it can't believe I missed that , thanks so much dude god bless you

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to the beginning of your `randomList()` method:

```
randomNum = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

One point that wasn't mentioned: always think about where you declare your variables and why. Doing so will help you to avoid such unintended consequences. In this case your randomNum list is only used inside of your randomList method. If you declare it inside of your method, it is recreated on each call and no more problem.

Comment: Why would scope be an issue?

Comment: Scope would only be the issue if you assumed those declarations are outside of the class (causing the error). I think its safe to assume they are inside of the class.

Comment: Maybe I phrased that wrong, but if randomNum was local to the randomList method it would solve the problem... no? Why is my answer wrong?

Comment: Yes, that would be a lot better phrasing. In that regard it does indeed solve the problem. Keep in mind that good answers explain **why** something is going wrong. Adding a solution is optional, but recommended. Give a complete answer next time and you'll avoid situations like this. It is not the issue at hand, but it would solve the problem though.

Comment: Understood, thank you. I was only trying to make the point that there was no need to declare it outside of the only method using it, and that can lead to unintended consequences

Comment: ;) Use these words and elaborate on the unintended consequences and you would've had a decent answer. If your answer is one line, it's probably not enough. Just something to keep in mind for future answers.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thank you for the constructive criticism. I have updated my post.